# Reading from a URLConnection

Tags: java, php, http, urlconnection

I have a php page in my server that accepts a couple of POST requests and process them. Lets say it's a simple page and the output is simply an echoed statement. With the URLConnection I established from a Java program to send the POST request, I tried to get the input using the input stream got through `connection.getInputStream()`. But All I get is the source of the page(the whole php script) and not the output it produces. We shall avoid socket connections here. Can this be done with Url connection or HttpRequest? How?

```
class htttp{
public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException{
    URL url=new URL("http://localhost/test.php");

    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    //((HttpURLConnection) conn).setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 

    wr.write("Hello");
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    InputStream ins = conn.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String inputLine;
    String result = "";
      while( (inputLine = in.readLine()) != null )
                result += inputLine;
        System.out.print(result);



    }
      }
```

I get the whole source of the webpage `test.php` in `result`. But I want only the output of the php script.

Comment: Do you have some sample code?

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Look at the edit.

Comment: If you get the content of the php script, you're webserver is certainly configured wrong and does not execute the script, but handle it as text. What happens when you browse to `http://localhost/test.php`? Is it executed then or offered for download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the PHP source itself, rather than the output it should be rendering, is that your local HTTP server - receiving your request targeted at `http://localhost/test.php` - decided to serve back the PHP source, rather than forward the HTTP request to a PHP processor to render the output.

Why this happens? that has to do with your HTTP server's configuration; there might be a few reasons for that. For starters, you should validate your HTTP server's configuration.

- Which HTTP server are you using on your machine?
- What happens when you browse `http://localhost/test.php` through your browser?

Comment: I'm using WAMP server and I get the ouput in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not the Java code - the problem lies with the web server. You need to investigate why your webserver is not executing your PHP script but sending it back raw. You can begin by testing using a simple PHP scipt which returns a fixed result and is accessed using a GET request (from a web browser). Once that is working you can test using the one that responds to POST requests.

Comment: I'm using $_REQUEST in php. Also, I get the output in my browser.